# WPF ComboBox which updates its ItemsSource from the database as the Text property changes

Tags: wpf, search, combobox, itemssource

I would like to have a `ComboBox` control on a form which will be used to search a list of investments as the user types.  I can do this easily if I cache the entire collection of investments from the database on startup (currently 3,000 or so items), but I would prefer to not do that if it isn't necessary.

The behavior that I am trying to implement is:

- The user types text into the editable ComboBox.
- As the user enters each character, the database search function is triggered, narrowing down the search results with each successive keystroke.
- As the search results are updated, the dropdown panel opens and displays the relevant matches

I have tried binding the `Text` property of the `ComboBox` to the `InvestmentName` (string) property on my `ViewModel`, and the `ItemsSource` property of the `ComboBox` to the `InvestmentList` (generic List) property on my `ViewModel`.  When I do this, the `Text` property auto-completes from the `ItemsSource`, however the dropdown appears empty.

I have been able to achieve these results using a `TextBox` stacked on top of a `ListBox`, but it isn't very elegant and it takes up more screen real estate.  I've also been able to get it to work with a `TextBox` stacked on top of a `ComboBox`, although the `ComboBox` steals the focus when the `IsDropDownOpen` property is set to "true" when there are valid search items.  It also isn't very visually pleasing to use two controls for this.

I feel like I'm really close to getting it to work the way I want it to, but there is something which eludes me.

The XAML for this control is:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Width="260" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          ItemsSource="{Binding InvestmentList}" DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
          IsDropDownOpen="{Binding DoShowInvestmentList}"
          ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsTemplate}" IsEditable="True" 
          Text="{Binding Path=InvestmentName, Mode=TwoWay,
                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The relevant `ViewModel` properties are:

```
    private bool _doShowInvestmentList;
    public bool DoShowInvestmentList
    {
        get { return _doShowInvestmentList; }
        set { if (_doShowInvestmentList != value) { _doShowInvestmentList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("DoShowInvestmentList"); } }
    }

    private List<PFInvestment> _investmentList;
    public List<PFInvestment> InvestmentList
    {
        get { return _investmentList; }
        set { if (_investmentList != value) { _investmentList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("InvestmentList"); } }
    }

    private string _investmentName;
    public string InvestmentName
    {
        get { return _investmentName; }
        set
        {
            if (_investmentName != value)
            {
                _investmentName = value;
                this.InvestmentList = DataAccess.SearchInvestmentsByName(value).ToList();

                if (this.InvestmentList != null && this.InvestmentList.Count > 0)
                    this.DoShowInvestmentList = true;
                else
                    this.DoShowInvestmentList = false;

                RaisePropertyChanged("InvestmentName");
            }
        }
    }
```

I've done a fair bit of research on this, but I haven't quite found the answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this great article on CodeProject by... me :)

[A Reusable WPF Autocomplete TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/autocomplete_textbox.aspx)

Look towards the end for the Google suggest example, it is similar to what you need, where every keypress triggers another query to the server.